# Maintaining "fitsSystemWindows" window insets through Scene Transition

Tags: android, transition, android-constraintlayout

I have a layout that transitions between 2 Scenes.

*layout.xml*

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/framelayout_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    // Some background views.

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/scene_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/scene_a" />
    </FrameLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

*res/layouts/scene_a.xml*

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    // Child views removed for brevity
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Scene B layout is identical.

In the activity, `ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(frameLayout, (v, insets) -> insets);` is called to use `fitsSystemWindows` with FrameLayout.

The views are correct on initial view inflation i.e views are drawn under the status bar, but content is pushed down by the window insets to avoid the status bar.

However, when I transition to Scene B, that padding provided by fitsSystemWindows is lost and the content jumps up. Scene A loses the padding too, when returning.

Any assistance greatly appreciated with how to keep this padding through the transitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so had nothing to do with Scene Transitions and everything to do with `android:fitsSystemWindows`.

The default behaviour for any view that uses `android:fitsSystemWindows` is to consume the window insets it gets passed. The insets get passed down depth first - see this [blog](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec#.n3a9rkigl).

So in my example above, the first scene - which has set `android:fitsSystemWindows` consumes the insets, so scene B does not get a chance. Similarly when I transition back to scene A (they have already been consumed).

The fix in my example was to remove the `android:fitsSystemWindows` from both scenes and place it in the scene root instead.